# remove blank lines in google sheet using formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with some contact info. Where some categories like 'promotion team', 'creative team'. I have created another sheet, and imported that information, put names under the category.

I have given a formula like this -

```
=IF(EXACT("Promotion & Marketing",Sheet1!E2), Sheet1!A2, " ")
```

but some line remains blank, how I can check, if this if statement false, then skip the line, don't leave it blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the content of A column.

I can't see your exact data so my answer may be not super precise but I think of something like that:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!E2:E="Promotion & Marketing")
```

This formula should display all the cells from A2:A range when there's "Promotion & Marketing" in corresponding row of E2:E column. With no blank rows.

Comment: yes, it works. can i run multiple filters in a single formula,actually I received another column to extract same category value in a single column.  I tried, =filter(sheet1!A2:A,sheet1!F2:F="Promotion & Marketing") & filter(sheet1!A2:A,sheet1!G2:G="Promotion & Marketing") , its returns only two names.

Comment: i solved it using + operator. =filter(sheet1!A2:A,(sheet1!F2:F="Promotion & Marketing")+(sheet1!A2:A,sheet1!G2:G="Promotion & Marketing")), given it if it can helps others.